# NodeJs + Express - Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, express

I run it in repl.it and I get the error **Cannot GET /**

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't work on the specific port which is 45799 but now it's not working again.

Here's the code:

````js
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
app.render('index', {
    bot: bot
}, (err, html) => {
    res.send(html)
    if (err) console.log(err)
})
});

app.get('/commands', (req, res) => {
app.render('commands', {
    bot: bot
}, (err, html) => {
    res.send(html)
    if (err) console.log(err)
})
});

app.get('/premium', (req, res) => {
app.render('premium', {
    bot: bot
}, (err, html) => {
    res.send(html)
    if (err) console.log(err)
})
});

app.get('/staff', (req, res) => {
app.render('staff', {
    bot: bot
}, (err, html) => {
    res.send(html)
    if (err) console.log(err)
})
})

let listener = app.listen(45799, (err) => {
     console.log('Your app is currently listening on port: ' + listener.address().port);
     if (err) console.log(err)
});```
````

Comment: Which route gives you that error?

Answer (score 1):

You rendering the wrong way. You have to use the `res` object instead of `app`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const bot = { "data": "1" }
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { bot: bot });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('server started');
});
```

Comment: Hi @prathamesh more, this is an unusual place to talk but can I talk to you on this chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/223388/talk-with-prathamesh-more?tab=access&highlight=6482248 . Funny thing is I just saw you on coding mentor 3 minutes ago and wanted to discuss a few things with you

Comment: It's fixed. It wasnt the codes problem. It was repl.it. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Express is a function that returns app.

And the app object has a method corresponding to http.

For example, put, get, post, etc.

This method takes a url as the first argument and a callback function as the second argument.

This callback function has three arguments: "req" for incoming request, "res" for response processing, and "next" to pass to the next middleware.

("req", "res" and "next" name is up to you.)

If you want to render ejs file, then use "res.render" not "app.render".

Comment: It's fixed. It wasnt the codes problem. It was repl.it. Thanks anyways!